# Deep learning: parameter selection and result interpretation

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning

I have a multiclass(7 labels) classification problem implemented in MLP. I am trying to classify 7 cancers based on some data. The overall accuracy is quite low, around 58%. However, some of the cancers is classified with accuracy around 90% for different parameters. Below cancer 1,2,3 etc means different types of cancer, For example 1= breast cancer, 2 = lung cancer etc. Now, for different parameter settings I get different classification accuracy. For example,

## 1. hyper parameters

```
    learning_rate = 0.001
    training_epochs = 10
    batch_size = 100
    hidden_size = 256
    #overall accuracy 53%, cancer 2 accuracy 91%, cancer 5 accuracy 88%, 
     #cancer 6 accuracy 89%
```

## 2. hyper parameters

```
    learning_rate = 0.01
    training_epochs = 30
    batch_size = 100
    hidden_size = 128
    #overall accuracy 56%, cancer 2 accuracy 86%, cancer 5 accuracy 93%, 
    #caner 6 accuracy 75%
```

As you can see, for different parameter settings I am getting totally different results. Cancer 1,3,4,7 have very low accuracy, so I excluded them. But cancer 2, 5,6 have comparatively better results. But, for cancer 6, the results vary by great number depending on the parameter settings.

An important note is, here overall accuracy is not important but if I can classify 2-3 cancers with more than 90% accuracy that is more important. So my question is, how do I interpret the results? In my paper how should I show the results? which parameter settings should I show/use? Or should I show different parameter settings for different cancer types? So basically, how to handle this type of situations?

Comment: How stable are these outcomes? If you re-run the model several times, what's the mean and std of these? As far as reporting, disease classification typically deals with very unbalanced classes and in this case accuracy is not a good metric. See [this](https://machinelearningmastery.com/tactics-to-combat-imbalanced-classes-in-your-machine-learning-dataset/), for example

Comment: Dataset is balanced. 10% difference between no of samples of different classes.

Comment: @asdfkjasdfjk Can you provide with more details of your code?

Answer (score 1):

You are training for very few epochs. The high variance could be a result of not running the training for long enough.

As far as showing the effect of hyperparameters on performance by class, a table could work. The rows could be the classes, the columns could be hyperparameter values, and the cell values could be the evaluation metric.